# laravel post request results in an error that method not allowed

Tags: laravel, post, request

```
<form id="login-form"  action="brand-dashboard" method="post">
        <span class"email">email</span>
        <input type="email" name="email">
        <span class"email">password</span>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">   
        <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

this is in my view page..then in my route..

```
Route::get('/brand-dashboard','BrandsController@auth_brand_admin');
```

in my Brands controller..i use the method like

```
public function auth_brand_admin()
    {               
        return ('sample text');
    }
```

but i got error when submiting the form ..the error is..

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to this

`Route::post('/brand-dashboard','BrandsController@auth_brand_admin')`;

It's because you register route with `GET` method but send `POST` request.